# Autofac: Resolving contructor parameters based on single dependency

Tags: autofac

I have a scenario which I want autofac to resolve:

Here are my classes, I would have a factory method to take NetworkCredentials and return TopLevel object, this should internally resolve the InnerType1 and InnerType2 with the NetwokCredentials

```
 public class TopLevel
{
    public TopLevel(InnerType1 type1, InnerType2 type2)
    {            
    }
}

public class InnerType1
{
    public InnerType1(NetworkCredential credential)
    {
    }
}
public class InnerType2
{
    public InnerType2(NetworkCredential credential)
    {
    }
}
```

Registration code > would something like this work ?

```
builder.Register<Func<NetworkCredential, TopLevel>>(c =>
        {
            var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return (cred) => context.Resolve<TopLevel>(new TypedParameter(typeof(NetworkCredential), cred));
        });
```

The crude approach could be to do resolve each contructor argument one by one inside resolution of TopLevel

Comment: As far as the class hierarchy is concerned the innerTypeN are wrapper over different network calls, which encapsulates businesslogic around handling request and response. TopLevel is an orchestrator, which does the job of aggregating typed reponses from the InnerTypeN classes.

Answer (score 1):

No, that will not work since you are now instructing Autofac to provide a parameter value of type `NetworkCredential` to the `TopLevel` constructor which clearly requires two parameters of  totally different types.

You will have to resolve `InnerType1` and `InnerType2` instances first and provide these to the `TopLevel` resolve. Something like this:

```cs
builder.Register<Func<NetworkCredential, TopLevel>>(c =>
    {
        var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return (cred) => {
            var i1 = context.Resolve<InnerType1>(TypedParameter.From(cred));
            var i2 = context.Resolve<InnerType2>(TypedParameter.From(cred));
            return context.Resolve<TopLevel>(TypedParameter.From(i1), TypedParameter.From(i2));
            };
    });
```

Note: I'm not seeing the whole picture of your system here, but if you feel that this is crude, perhaps you should look at revising your class hierarchy. IMO there's a faint smell of "too complex" in your code here, you require two different classes to be configured with the same *data* which makes me want to de-duplicate :)

Comment: Thanks Peter, This is the approach I have taken for now. But Its a little to coupled with the contructor signature.

Comment: As far as the class hierarchy is concerned the innerTypeN are wrapper over different network calls, which encapsulates businesslogic around handling request and response. TopLevel is an orchestrator, which does the job of aggregating typed reponses from the InnerTypeN classes.

Comment: Another approach is to move this into a TopLevelFactory Class and move the dependency on contructor from glue code to BusinessLogic.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Peter's answer, but slightly different flavor:

```cs
builder.Register<Func<NetworkCredential, TopLevel>>(c =>
{
    var resolveInnerType1 = c.Resolve<Func<NetworkCredential, InnerType1>>();
    var resolveInnerType2 = c.Resolve<Func<NetworkCredential, InnerType2>>();
    var resolveTopLevel = c.Resolve<Func<InnerType1, InnerType2, TopLevel>>();

    return (cred) => {
            var i1 = resolveInnerType1(cred);
            var i2 = resolveInnerType2(cred);
            return resolveTopLevel(i1, i2);
        };
});
```